# Arranging corresponding values in descending manner

Tags: java

I have two sets of columns right now but I am not sure how do I program it and what set of class for me to use it. Both are in separate arrays. One for letters and the other for the numbers.

```
 a  12
 b  9
 c  156
```

So a corresponds to 12 and b corresponds to 9 etc etc. The list is actually a frequency of letters in a text file so I have 26 of them.
Both are not in the same array. As I have separate arrays for both of them. I want to try and arrange
and make them be in a descending manner.
So that the output would be:

```
 c   156
 a   12
 b   9
```

I'm still unsure about various capabilities of ArrayList or HashMap or Tree Map. So any help with this?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String,Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap(bvc);

        map.put("A",5);
        map.put("B",60);
        map.put("C",65);
        map.put("D",3);

        System.out.println("unsorted map");
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key/value: " + key + "/"+map.get(key));
        }

        sorted_map.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("results");
        for (String key : sorted_map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key/value: " + key + "/"+sorted_map.get(key));
        }
    }

}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator {

  Map base;
  public ValueComparator(Map base) {
      this.base = base;
  }

  public int compare(Object a, Object b) {

    if((Integer)base.get(a) < (Integer)base.get(b)) {
      return 1;
    } else if((Integer)base.get(a) == (Integer)base.get(b)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that has the character and the frequency as data member, and make the class implements [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

There are 2 options here, you can either:

- Insert all objects into a class that implements [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface (e.g. [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)). Then call [`Collections.sort(List<T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) on the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).
- Insert all objects into [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). You can obtain the sorted item via `iterator()`.

From the question, it seems that the 2 pieces of data are not members of some existing object in the first place. If any chance that they do, you don't have to create a new class for the character and frequency. You can insert the existing object into a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), implement a class that extends on [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface, and sort the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) with [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: Ok, if I use SortedSet, how do I add both arrays to the sorted set?

Comment: 'set.add(alphabets,alphabetfrequency)' ?

Comment: @nfnmy: You need to create a class that contains character and frequency. Create such object for every frequency entries, then insert those into `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following two lists.

```
[a, b, c] 
[12, 9, 156]
```

First, *zip* the two lists together, so that you get a list (or a projection thereof) of *tuples*.

```
[(a, 12), (b, 9), (c, 156)]
```

Then sort this list *by* second item in each tuple, with whatever *ordering* you want.

```
[(c, 156), (a, 12), (b, 1)]
```

Now *unzip* this back into the two lists.

```
[c, a, b]
[156, 12, 1]
```

And there's your answer.

The italicized words indicate the generic abstractions used in the above solution, all of which are likely already available in [this](http://functionaljava.org/) library.

Comment: For what it's worth, a Haskell solution using the above method: http://ideone.com/XEzt7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    char[] letters = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    int[] numbers = { 12, 9, 156 };
    printDescendind(letters, numbers);
}

public static void printDescendind(char[] letters, int[] numbers) {
    class Holder implements Comparable<Holder> {
        char letter;
        int number;
        public int compareTo(Holder o) {
            return number != o.number ? o.number - number : letter - o.letter;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s   %s", letter, number);
        }
    }
    List<Holder> list = new ArrayList<Holder>(letters.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        Holder h = new Holder();
        h.letter = letters[i];
        h.number = numbers[i];
        list.add(h);
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    for (Holder holder : list) {
        System.out.println(holder);
    }
}
```